# Searching JSTOR API using Javascript

Tags: javascript

im writing a web app in javascript which creates harvard style references for a source.

I was hoping let the user search for journals and articles, and have the form prepopulated

to search the JSTOR library for data they have an SRU interface at http://dfr.jstor.org/sru/ which returns XML for search queries. (e.g. http://dfr.jstor.org/sru/?operation=searchRetrieve&query=dc.title+%3D+%22test%22&version=1.1)

Is there a way to get this xml using javascript?

Ive tried using a jquery ajax request as follows:

```
var jstor = "http://dfr.jstor.org/sru/?operation=searchRetrieve&query=dc.title+%3D+%22test%22&version=1.1"
$.ajax({
    url: jstor,
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

But i get an error in firebug "407 Proxy Authentication Required", any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you aren't authorized.  You need to get an API key in order to access the data.